# Automatically start Amazon EC2 instance if state is stopped

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

If my instance state is stopped how can automatically start?

Need to check every minute state of instance.

EDIT: Have few instances activated and need to check for every instance.

Comment: First, a question: why is your instance stopping outside of your control? You can create an alarm to warn you if status checks fails and you can automate some remedial action (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/monitoring-system-instance-status-check.html#creating_status_check_alarms) using SNS/Lambda.

Comment: I have task for shutdown. Not out of my control. I need to know how to start if is stopped.

Comment: WHY do you want to start it again after it stops? Why is it stopping? If you can provide more information, we will be able to provide you with a better answer.

Comment: This cannot be done via a configuration in the Console. It can be done with some scripting. What is your preferred language? Are you on Windows or Linux, or would you prefer Lambda?

Comment: Just need to know how to start EC2 again if it is stopped. Using Windows instances.

Comment: As @jarmod mentioned you need to use CloudWatch to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

John Rotenstein is asking you some good questions, that may lead to a better answer, but if you just want to know how to start an instance:

```
aws ec2 start-instances --instance-ids i-1234567890abcdef0
```

where i-1234567890abcdef0 is the instance id you want to start.

Comment: Okay, I have 3 instances and I want to shut down it after 1 hour and need to start it again after 1 minute when is stopped. How can do it? In Windows I will add task to shut down after 1 hour but I don't know how to start it again.